# Filter data inside custom Processor module?

Tags: spring-xd

I am writing a custom Processor module using a transformer class, 
and for some input, I do not want the transformer to generate any output, how can I do that?

I tried to return null in the transform() method, but that make Spring-xd runtime generate exceptions.
And I do not want to use a Filter in the stream definition because that will be overkill for me.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformers always require a reply.

Use a `<service-activator/>` instead, with `requires-reply="false"`.